# Building dmg for electron app on MacOS takes 2-3 minutes

Tags: macos, windows-10, electron, electron-packager

My electron app is pretty small it has a few javascript files (aside from the package.json and main.s), 3 html files, and some images. Yet for some reason it is taking 2-3 minutes to package into a dmg with a file size around 1.33GB (give or take). Any ideas as to why and how I can fix this?

Side note: on my pc (Windows 10 pro latest version) I have installed electron-windows-store multiple times but every time i export it keeps telling me "electron-packager" is not recognized as an internal or external command

it also does this for electron-packager. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Having 2-3 minutes of build time is not unusual for an Electron App. If the resulting package is 1.33 GB then you either have tons of assets (videos etc.) or you're packaging lots of (probably unnecessary) dependencies.

I suggest you extract and unpack the ASAR file from the resulting DMG and check what assets are packaged inside. Here is how:

1. Install the `asar` package globally

```
npm install -g asar
```

2. Change into your app directory

```
cd /Applications/MyHugeApp.app/Contents/Resources
```

3. Create a temporary folder to extract the content

```
mkdir temp-source
```

4. Unpack the app.asar file into the directory

```
asar extract app.asar temp-source
```

Now you can analyze the files inside `temp-source` and check how (and where) the space is used.